# Which online sources provide narrow transcriptions for English?

Tags: english, dictionary, american-english, online-resources

I've tried a dozen of online English dictionaries, and all of them give broad transcriptions. So it's impossible to tell from them, for example, how many aspirated "p"s there are in "appropriate". What online dictionary(-ies), if any, provide(s)  narrow transcriptions for (preferably American) English with all details?

Comment: Narrow transcriptions vary widely between different dialects of English. So you're not going to find them, and if you do they would only tell you things like how a fairly small group of native English speakers from Southern England pronounce words.

Comment: The flags "not suitable for this site" and "needs more clarity" are both nonsense. OP might be happy with phonetics from any dialect, or they could specify. The question is reasonably clear. I don't see which site guideline this would be violating